# How to plot data from different runs on one figure in Spyder

Tags: ipython, spyder

What I meant by the title is that I have two different programs and I want to plot data on one figure. In Matlab there is this definition for figure handle which eventually points to a specific plot. Let's say if I call figure(1) the first time, I get a figure named ''1'' created. The second I call figure(1), instead of creating a new one, Matlab simply just plot on the previous figure named ''1''. I wondered how I can go about and do that in Spyder.

I am using Matplotlib in sypder. I would imagine this could be easily achieved. But I simply don't know much about this package to figure my problem out. :(

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

One way that I have figured out is to define a dictionary and then record the results you want individually. Apparently, this is not the most efficient way, but it works.